# Starting a family fund, owned by a parent company?

Tags: stocks, investing, limited-liability-company, family, private-company

first post here.

I have been doing some research, but I am still not 100% sure on this. A little background: I live in NY state, have a Bachelors Degree in finance and data analytics.

My situation: I am looking to create an exempt private fund for my family to invest. Is this situation feasible:
Form a partnership entity for the fund, have my family and I as limited partners. Form and LLC to act as general partner and make investment decisions on their behalf. In this situation, I would be relying on the exemption of Rule 506(b), Exemption 3(c)(1), and be an Exempted Reporting Adviser.

Furthermore, I currently have a general partnership “investment club” with my brother. If the above is not practical, could I make an LLC and “own” the investment club? Thanks.

I understand that the first situation would require filing Form D. But how frequent is the filing? My family wants to put funds in every week (for example, $25). Does that mean I need to submit a Form D weekly?

Comment: What amounts are you talking about here? Why is such a structure even necessary?